# How to manipulate integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration

How would one prove that

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{\sin x} \sin^2 x\, dx = 1/2\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{\sin x}  (1 + \sin x \cos^2 x)\, dx $$

Comment: It is not we who manipulate the integrals, it is they that manipulate us, by taunting us, daring us, and challenging us to solve them... :-)

Comment: I deleted my answer since I only took into account the $1/2$ in front of the rhs but ignored the removal of the $1/2$ in the exponential term. The integrals are equal but I have to leave now. I shall try later.

Answer (score 1):

As $\displaystyle2e^{\sin x}\sin^2x=e^{\sin x}(1-\cos2x)=e^{\sin x}-e^{\sin x}\cos2x$

$$\int_0^{\frac\pi2}e^{\sin x}(2\sin^2x)\ dx=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}e^{\sin x}\ dx-\int_0^{\frac\pi2}e^{\sin x}\cos2x\ dx\  \ \ \  (1)$$

Now integrating by parts, $\displaystyle\int e^{\sin x}\cos2x\ dx=e^{\sin x}\int\cos2x\ dx-\left(\frac{d(e^{\sin x})}{dx}\cdot \int\cos2x\ dx\right)\ dx$

$\displaystyle=e^{\sin x}\cdot\frac{\sin2x}2-\int e^{\sin x}\cos x\cdot\frac{\sin2x}2\ dx $

$\displaystyle=\frac{e^{\sin x}\cdot\sin2x}2-\int e^{\sin x}\cos^2 x\sin x\ dx $

$\displaystyle\implies\int_0^{\frac\pi2}e^{\sin x}\cos2x\ dx$

$\displaystyle=\frac{e^{\sin x}\cdot\sin2x}2\large|_0^{\frac\pi2}-\int_0^{\frac\pi2}e^{\sin x}\cos^2 x\sin x\ dx$

$\displaystyle=-\int_0^{\frac\pi2}e^{\sin x}\cos^2 x\sin x\ dx$ as $\sin\pi=\sin0=0$

Put this value of $\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac\pi2}e^{\sin x}\cos2x\ dx$ in $(1)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $I$ and $J$ denote the left-hand and right hand integrals respectively. Observe that:
\begin{eqnarray*}
J &=& 1/2\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{\sin x}\ dx + 1/4\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{\sin x} \cos x \cdot \sin 2x\ \ dx\\
&=& 1/2\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{\sin x}\ dx + 1/4\left(\underbrace{\left[ e^{\sin x}\sin 2x \right]_0^{\pi/2}}_{=\ 0} - \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{\sin x} \cdot \underbrace{2\cos 2x}_{=\ 2(1-2\sin ^2x) } dx\right) & \text{(via parts)}\\
&=& 1/2\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{\sin x}\ dx  -1/4\int_0^{\pi/2} 2e^{\sin x}\ dx +1/4 \int_0^{\pi/2}4 e^{\sin x} \sin^2x \ dx\\
&=& \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{\sin x} \sin^2 x\, dx\\
\\
\\
\\
&=& I
\end{eqnarray*}